# How do I know which div was clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a game of tic-tac-toe using HTML5, CSS and JavaScript. I have identified the winning patterns and more or less how to make it work. There is no artificial intelligence involved; it is intended to be a **player-vs-player-on-the-same-computer** game.

[image]

All I want to do is:

Know when a div is clicked

Know **which** div is clicked

Please tell me if that is possible. If yes, how. Steps appreciated, don't post complete code :)

Comment: @techfoobar Yes, I like it :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: Would you accept a solution using jQuery?

Comment: Try [`e.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.currentTarget)/[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in the event handler or maybe [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.target)

Comment: @Jonast92: Not for learning JavaScript

Comment: @Bergi Maybe he doesn't care really and just want the job done.

Comment: Getting the job done is something different than introducing some bloated and unnecessary external library for now apparent reason.

Comment: I agree with @PeeHaa埽. I am new to all this. I am just learning a few concepts from a book then pushing my creativity to the max to see what I can do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind [an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.addEventListener) to the container, then examine the [`target` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.target) of the event object to determine which element was clicked.

Seriously consider replacing the `<div>`s with `<button>`s as they are designed to be interactive (so have benefits such as automatically appearing in the focus order).

Comment: Ok, suggestion accepted. There will be a lot of `button` returned as a result of `document.querySelectorAll("button")`. All the `button` will have the same listener?

Comment: @LittleChild — No. Have a single listener on the container.

Comment: You can make all the buttons have the same listener, but you can have each button having a unique id so you can know which one was clicked.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you so much. Highly appreciated. The book uses `function TextHandler(event){...}` for handling text input and using `event.keycode` determines if enter was pressed. Every event handler function can have some argument passed to it ? And then the argument will contain relevant information ?

Comment: The first argument any event handler will receive will be an [event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event). Sometimes the properties it has will vary depending on the type of event. There wouldn't be a keycode for a click event, for instance.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry if my question was too stupid. I am a novice Java programmer who started with game designing using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

`this`, if you are using jquery, it can be super simple:

```
$("div.box").on("click", function() { $(this).addClass("clicked"); });
```

the above would check for any div with the class "box", and add a "clicked" class to it

not sure why this was downvoted.. here is an example showing it working.. even for a sample of what I think was needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/LCKr6/1/

Comment: The OP did not state the desire to use jquery as a solution would be the reason.

Comment: @Xotic750, the answer was using `this`, jquery was just used in an example of `this` being used.

Comment: You could change your answer to reflect vanilla javascript.

Answer (score -4):

It is possible, you should use javascript (JQuery) for this. You can register listeners for mouse click where you can catch the id of div that was clicked

Comment: 1. jQuery will make it easy, but no needed as such. 2. Telling it is possible isn't an answer.